# how to make full screen activity with status bar on top of it while scrollbar is not scrolling full in Activity when it focus on editText?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-scrollview

[image: My layout before typing text into EditText]

[image: My layout after typing text into EditText]

Issue is that when I enter text in **EditText** then ScrollView does not work and does not scroll in my activity

```
     fun statusBarColor(activity: Activity) {


     val window = activity.window
    // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
   // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
 //window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);            
    // finally change the color
    //window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    //window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
      //Manifest code on activity.
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: have you found your solution @Ankit?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) as your root and [NestedScrolView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) in it .

**CoordinatorLayout** as root reacts to keyboard and  scrolls  your layout to the top of your phone with  assistant of **NestedScrollView**  which your **NestedScrollView** includes your layout code .

To put the issue into perspective view

**CoordinaterLayout > NestedScrolView > yourLayout**

Change your layout **XMl** like code below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- rest of your layout xml code-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But its not working I have used already this can you give me nay other best solution.

Comment: set your **ScrollView** height to  wrapContent
If it does not work please add your layout Xml file to your question 
maybe I can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.iv_background);
```

set `initViews()` to `SignIn` activity and make it transparent to:

```xml
 <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#00000000</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having an activity and content layout file. From your example, we could have activity_login and content_login. In this example, I will assume that your activity is called `LoginActivity.class`, so please update accordingly.

## activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_user_profile" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## content_user_profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Have all your layout here as scrollviews expect one child. You can replace LinearLayout above with constraintLayout for more flexibility and responsiveness.-->

    </Linearlayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

## Manifest code for that particular activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:colorMode="wideColorGamut"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:theme="@style/..."
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but it might help someone.

Use this code to make status bar transparent and to set status bar and navigation bar text and icon color(change navigation bar properties based on your needs):

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars =
        false
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars =
        !isUsingNightModeResources()
```

And this listener to set insets manually(for example when your keyboard is shown):

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { view, windowInsets ->
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())

        view.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            updateMargins(insets.left, insets.top, insets.right, insets.bottom)
        }
        WindowInsetsCompat.Builder().setInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime(), insets).build()
    }
```

And use this to revert it if needed:

```
if (!isUsingNightModeResources()) {
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars =
            true
    }
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
    window.statusBarColor = getColor(R.color.your_color)
```

isUsingNightModeResources is an extension in this case, but you might not need it:

```
fun Context.isUsingNightModeResources(): Boolean {
return when (resources.configuration.uiMode and
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> true
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> false
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> false
    else -> false
}
```

}

This solution works for api >= 21